# Vaadin Design context with html

Tags: java, html, netbeans, vaadin

I have problems with Vaadin Framework. I want to learn to program Ui's with html, of type:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <v-vertical-layout size-full="true">
        <v-label><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></v-label>
        <v-horizontal-layout>
            <vaadin-button _id="login">Login</vaadin-button>
            <vaadin-button _id="signup">Sign up</vaadin-button>
        </v-horizontal-layout>
    </v-vertical-layout>
</body>
```

And also I implement the Ui.java:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
@Widgetset("tad.proyecto.madrigalgutierrezpedroantonio.MyAppWidgetset")
public class Principal extends UI {

private Button login;
private Button signup;

public Principal(){

}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    setContent(Design.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Principal.html")));
    iniciarComponentes();
}

private void iniciarComponentes() {
    login = new Button();
    signup = new Button();
    getPage().setTitle("Gestión de ligas");
}

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = Principal.class, productionMode = false)
public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
}
```

The code is working, but I don't know how set styles for buttons, labels, etc. (ex. style="position: absolute; left: 500px;")

Other problem is when I click "Ctrl + Space" I don't see "suggestions" of vaadin tags. I'm working with Netbeans.

Comment: Please correct your code formatting in the question. You already have specified your own theme by annotation, so you should define styles for widgets like button in your theme. Theming is covered by [Vaadin Docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-creating.html).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. So I understood that I can't stylize in html :-(

Comment: ng-style? you need to explain what you try to achieve, if you are trying to combine angular and vaadin.

Comment: No no, that part of the code isn't valid. Excuse me.